# Изменение имен объектов в цикле

Tags: c++, qt

Здравствуйте! Пишу код в qt creator. Создал 10 объектов QLineEdit через дизайнер, необходимо каждому QLineEdit задать текст из массива name[].
У меня есть:

```
ui->Edit_1->setText(name[0]);
ui->Edit_2->setText(name[1]);
ui->Edit_3->setText(name[2]);
ui->Edit_4->setText(name[3]);
ui->Edit_5->setText(name[4]);
ui->Edit_6->setText(name[5]);
ui->Edit_7->setText(name[6]);
ui->Edit_8->setText(name[7]);
ui->Edit_9->setText(name[8]);
ui->Edit_10->setText(name[9]);
```

Вопрос: как сделать это все в три строки циклом, ведь нужно заменять только цифру после слова "Edit_"?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужен метод `objectName`, возвращающий строку - имя объекта, в сочетании с методом `findChild`, осуществляющим поиск дочернего объекта по имени. Примерно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    QLineEdit *edit = findChild<QLineEdit *>("Edit_" + QString::number(i));
    if (edit == nullptr) continue;  //вдруг объект не найден
    edit->setText(name[i]);
}
```

Для созданных из дизайнера объектов `objectName` прописывается автоматически, при создании из кода, возможно, вам придется прописать `objectName` вручную.