# Как обойти в цикле все QCheckBox

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gui

Я добавил в окно 10 чекбоксов в режиме дизайнера. Это объекты `checkbox1,checkbox2,...,checkbox10`, не являющиеся массивом. Как мне проверить состояние каждого чекбокса в цикле?

Comment: Если рефакторинг с применением массива категорически неприемлем - используйте массив адресов, засуньте в него адреса чекбоксов и работайте в цикле с этим массивом адресов...

Comment: Проблема в том, что в режиме дизайнера я не могу класть эти чекбоксы в массив, а перспектива переписывать все окно через создание кодом меня удручает.

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот вопрос, тут сходная ситуация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590962/Изменение-имен-объектов-в-цикле/590970#590970

Comment: О, спасибо, такой вариант меня в целом устраивает, правда я тут еще нашел такую штуку как QButtonGroup, она кажется прямо для этого и создана.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы обойти все дочерние объекты определённого типа можно использовать [`QObject::findWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren). Пример:

```
for (auto child: parentWidget.findChildren<QCheckBox*>())
{
    // Работаем с child как QCheckBox*
    if (child->isChecked()) ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если категорически не хочется создавать форму процедурно, то можно перебирать дочерние элементы. Метод

```
QObjectList &QObject::children()
```

вам в помощь. QObjectList объявлен в Qt вот так

```
typedef QList<QObject*> QObjectList;
```

Далее перебираем элементы в поисках элементов с нужным именем (далее код выполняем внутри класса окна после инициализации ui). Если найден нужный объект, то преобразуем его в QCheckBox c помощью qobject_cast. Можно сразу поместить указатели на них в QList или QMap.

```
QObjectList childs = this->children();
QMap<QString, QCheckBox*> boxMap;
QList<QCheckBox*> boxList;
QList<QObject*>::iterator i;
for (i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i){
    if (i->objectName().left(8) == "checkbox"){
        QCheckBox *box = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(i);
        if (box){
            boxMap[box->objectName()] = box;
            boxList.append(box);
        }
    }
}
```

Также можно использовать findChild, чтобы получить указатели на дочерние элементы по имени и классу или findChildren для поиска дочерних элементов хоть по строке хоть по RegExp.

Comment: Зачем эти костыли, если можно сразу использовать [`findChildren`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren)?

Comment: Например для обхода всех дочерних объектов или для поиска среди них по нескольким условиям - один проход вместо нескольких поисков будет эффективнее. Также условия поиска могут быть любыми т.к. задаются кодом, а не строкой или RegExp. В вашем случае эффективнее будет findChildren по RegExp.

Comment: Я к тому, что исходить следует из решаемой задачи. Если готовые функции решают проблему, то рукописных решений стоит избегать. Если же гибкости библиотечных вариантов недостаточно, то, конечно, приходится велосипедить.